# Attempting to insert an image into a sqlite database API 21

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I'm new to android so forgive me if this is an easy question, but I'm attempting to insert an image to my database in API 21 so i cannot make use of `Files.readAllBytes`. I found some code on here that converts the image into an array but im not sure how it works, and not sure what it returns. I want to then use the array and do a `ContentValues.put("Head", (the array) )`. Thanks all in advance.

```
public boolean insertAvatar(Image Head) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //File head = new File("C:capaa\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\head2.png");

    File head = new File("C:capaa\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\head2.png"); 
    try {
        read(head); // calling the convert method on my head file 
    }catch (IOException e){ }
    ContentValues.put("Head",head); // this is the line im not sure about 

    long ins = db.insert("Avatar", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

//converts to bytes
public byte[] read(File file) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
    InputStream ios = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ios = new FileInputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }finally {
        try {
            if (ous != null)
                ous.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            if (ios != null)
                ios.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return ous.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional that backslashes are missing after `C:` in `"C:capaa\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\head2.png"`? And why an apparent Windows path if this should be for Android?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting an image to an SQLite database for API 21 (JDK6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096930/inserting-an-image-to-an-sqlite-database-for-api-21-jdk6)

Comment: @stickybit I was trying to get an image in my drawable folder and just cut the path as it was massive for this post. Do you know best way to get to a drawable file, or is the only way to list the whole path? Can i simply do "drawable/head2.png"

Comment: @stickybit I've also tried "String HeadUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.head2;" but still isn't recognized in the read method cri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why would you insert a whole image into your db? when you have few options like below?**

> **Opt1**: save the image locally on the device storage and store the path to your db which is a string.
>
> **Opt2**: Using a well optimized image library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) and load image directly from link, [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) will catch the images for you at a very nice level, you can read more about the way the library caches it files if you want to know more.
>
> **Opt3**: @MikeT answer above, like he said, you might have issues retrieving the data when image size exceed 1MB, inanition to that, it will make your database so much heavy, so there for it's not a good approach.
>
> **Few tips on opt1:**
>
> You can create a simple table looking like below:

[image]

**Few tips on opt2:**

> add `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` to your build.gradle(Module: app) and build.
>
> Then you can use library like below:

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(imgUrl)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)/*just incase fetching image failed, this drawable will show up instead. it's up to you, you can remove it either way.*/
    .into(imageView);//a reference to the imageView you want to display the image on
```

> Goodluck, hopefully it does help.

Answer (score 1):

The **read** method should return a byte[], you can then simply use :-

```
ContentValues.put("Head",read(head));
```

The **insert** conevience method converts the byte[] returned from the **read** into the appropriate string x'f1f2f3f0......', where each hex value is a byte in the array, this being the string used in the SQL that is generated by the **insert** convenience method.

- Note that if the images are close to 1MB, or definitely 2MB in size then you may have issue retrieving the data as a CursorWindow (the buffer into which rows are stored) was 1MB later version it is 2MB. As a least 1 row (very inefficient) must fit into a CursorWindow.
- In general it is not recommended to store images in the database but rather to store the path to the image file in the database.

Comment: what do you think about writing such an enormous data into an sqlite database? won't it slow down the readings? also I don't if ContentValues.put function  will give you the a length of what byte can actually take since byte can only hold values ranging from -128 to 127. mind sharing more?
Also, what is the maximum length of string a column can contain in sqlite? I will research on this though.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, just a quick question, i think my path to my file is wrong. I tried using String "HeadUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.head2;" but still no luck